# what method to use to determine my result is statistical significant?

Tags: r, probability

I gathered the cars sales data from public, 2552 people who traded in their Mazda, bought the different car brand below, Can I conclude that people who own Mazda are more likely to buy Honda? what method to use determine my result is statistically significant?  how to add confident interval or margin of error? can anyone show me the calculation?

```
    own Mazda
Acura   12
Audi    13
BMW     8
Buick   3
Cadillac    0
Chevrolet   331
Chrysler    51
Dodge   64
Ford    404
GMC 14
Honda   1652
```

Comment: I've given you a hint ... if you can collapse the values to (number buying Honda) vs. (number buying any other brand), then you can use `prop.test()` to test against a null hypothesis of equal probability (p=0.5). (If that's not enough of a hint, I respectfully question whether you're qualified for the job ...)

Comment: you could look at the information on "binomial test" on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_test) ...

Comment: Hey Mr.  @BenBolker Bolker, I posted my answer below using test statistic, not sure if that works, I going to learn prop.test() as you mention.

Answer (score -1):

Use test statistic to do

```
Honda/Mazda = 1652/2552= 64.7%
set Hypothesis 
Ho: p = 0.64      (claim)
Ha: p ≠ 0.64
test statistic = (0.647-0.64)/√(0.64*0.36/2552) = 0.73 allow me to find p-value
p-value = 0.2673 (search it on z-table)
if p-value <= α, then reject null hypothesis
if p-value > α, then fail to null hypothesis, since  0.267> α = 0.05
Conclusion: there’s enough evidence to support the claim that 64% of car buyer who own Mazda are more likely to buy a Honda.


Solution 2: use prop.test() in R
prop.test(x=1652,n = 2552, p=0.64)
not sure if I set it up correctly?
```

Comment: A null hypothesis that p=0.64 does not test the claim that those who 
"own Mazda are more likely to buy Honda." Is that what you really want to know? Where did 64% come from? Also, the last sentence is not correct, to claim that you need to decide how close to 64% is close enough and then see if the confidence bound is within that range.

Comment: Aaron, the p=0.64 come from 1652/2552= 64.7%, please advise how to set it up correctly, I also post a different solution using R

Comment: It is invalid to formulate your test hypothesis based on the observed outcomes--that would allow statistical tests to prove both that every dataset is "significant" and to demonstrate that no data are "significant"! The software you choose to use will not protect you from such a fundamental conceptual error: it will gladly output good-looking results. That is why @BenBolker, who is an `R` expert, directed you to a Wikipedia article rather than recommending code.